# Best way to access 2D data

Tags: c#, arrays, ienumerable

Would like to know which is the best way to access 2D data in C#(.Net Framework 3.5)
I am trying to do a simple masking application that will mask a set of numbers (0-9) to a series of letters. The number that needs to be masked is the columnName and the codition is the rowName.

I have used both jagged array and 2D arrays. Are there any other ways to do so which is efficient in terms of coding and running the console application. Using the rowName (string) and columnName (int) I should be able to select the data

So if the number i am masking is 5 and the condition is "third" than the masked value should be **ce**

```
aa ab ac ad ae af
ba bb bc bd be bf
ca cb cc cd ce cf
da db dc dd de df
ea eb ec ed ee ef
```

Its is very tiring process if the masking table changes, as i will need to go alot of places to edit the code. I must be able to access the other around also.

If i give ba and the condition "second" than i should be able to retrieve the columnName as 1.

So in other words all the data in column 1 will have a value of 1 no mather what the condition is.

Which will it be better ENUMs,List or other STD containers.

Please advice. And a sinnpet of how to access the data will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "third" row and 5th column doesn't end up at **de**. Are they 0-based or 1-based?

Comment: Is this just a coding exercise? What will be the purpose for this code? With the informations you are providing I would say that a 2D-array is sufficient. For more complex situations you should consider to store your 'masking-data' in a database. And before we post code, you should post code ;).

Comment: @Dennis_E, sorry abt that i have made the amendments. They are 1-based

Comment: @user1567896 As, I have indicated, I have already know how to do in 2D array. I would like to know is there other STD containers which can be more efficient. According to my manager, 2D array is resource intensive. I am kinda, new to Enums and ICollections

Comment: A 2D array is not resource intensive. Where does your manager get that from? A jagged array is resource intensive.

Comment: @M.A And as I have indicated a 2d-Array is sufficient for the informations you are providing ;). How many entries will the array have? What is the purpose of your code? What have you done so far? Answer these questions and we can give you better advice.

Comment: The most difficult part is to translate english words (like "third") to numbers. I'd probably use a dictionary for that. The rest is easy.

Comment: @user1567896 There will be 310 entries. The main purpose is to masking of a set of numbers such as 78546213 into aaabbcbddedfaacc. 10 digits will become 30 alphabets. I currently using a jagged array.

Comment: @Dennis_E, My bad, currently i am using a jagged array. Thats y my manager says it is recource intensive. And accessing the data is also not efficient in terms of coding. The conditions are not exactly "third" but "03". I can actually change them into integer, but i only worry, it will confuse with the columnName since the columnName is integer also.

Comment: With 310 entries it does not matter what you are using, you will not see any relevant differences. And I would use an integer for the condition as well as it is... well, an integer. Don't make it too complicated. Why not simply ask the user: "Please enter a number:"... and then "Please enter condition (1-5)"...

Comment: Another thing to consider: You said that the mapping values may change. In this case it is NOT a good idea to hard-code those values because you must edit your source-code if the values change. Better put the values in a file or a database in this case.

Comment: Example of converting char to int: `('c' - 'a' + 1 == 3)` and int to char: `(char)(5 + 'a' - 1) == 'e'`.

Comment: Never trust your manager. Always check things yourself. Nothing wrong with using a 2D array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two main problems here. One is the coding and second is method of access to data.

Regarding the data access, the best option would be pipe architecture. Best choice for that would be reading directly bytes from resource.

Your coding table is just matrix and can be stored in form of single array

```
char[] coding = {'','a','b','c','d','e',...};

int coder = nextCoder(); //3
int value = nextValue(); //5 

char x = coding[coder]; //c
char y = coding[value]; //e
```

For this example I assume that your input has only ANSII , this mean for input like 1234567 you will have to read row of byte[] `31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38`.

```
byte[] input  =    {x31,x32,x33,x34,x35,x36,x37,x38};
byte[] coding = {x00,x61,x62,x63,x64,x65,...} //'','a','b','c','d','e'
```

What we can notice is that integers form 0 to 9 are coded from 30 to 39 and letters from a to e are coded from 61 to 66.

So for values like:

```
byte coder = nextCoder(); //3
byte value = nextValue(); //35
```

We can use that arithmetic instead of arrays

```
byte x = 60 + coder; //63
byte y = 30 + value; //65
```

So finally to encode

```
byte[] line = new byte[lineLenght]; //We create our buffers. 
byte[] code = new byte(line.length*2);

while(hasMoreLines) {

  readLine(line);

  for(int i=0, j=0; i < line.length; i++) {
   code[j++] = x60 + coder;
   code[j++] = x30 + line[i];
  }
  writeLine(code);
}
```

For this example your pipe line requires only two byte arrays for storing input and output while processing.